# ASP.NET Core EF DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I was trying to manually implement a cascade delete in my ASP.NET Core website.
So, I got a Poll section which is based on 3 entities: PollQuestion, PollOption, PollAnswer.
I'm starting this by deleting all the answers, and this goes fine, then I move to deleting the options with this code:

```
if (answersDeleted) {
    options = GetOptionsList(_pollID);
    context.PollOption.RemoveRange(options);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return true;
} else { 
    return false;
}
```

When the `SaveChanges()` is executed I get this exception:

*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 2 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.*

So. I can't really understand why he was expecting to affect 1 row since I pass a list to `RemoveRange()`.

Comment: I had the same problem today at work. Turns out that by the time the SaveChanges executed one of the entities had already been deleted by another part of my program.

Comment: I Dont think its the same issue here, its pretty much all there whats going on between the "get", "remove" and "save" operations.

Comment: it would be better to post this as an answer. In the comments it will be not easy to found this.

Comment: Yeh, you are right, done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone could make use of this one day.... i found the problem, it wasn't strictly related to the chunk of code i posted; few days ago i modified the poll table, and changed the Key, from a single field key to a composite key, then i forgot to reflect that change in my Model, which still was using a single key. It wasn't returning any error so i didn't notice this until i had to do other stuff on the DB and there i found the problem.